# When an input number is given as input. The input digit should be read and nearest cubic root value will be displayed as output

Tags: cubic

For example:

`Input = 21`

Nearest cubic root values for above digit are: 2 and 3

- `8 = 2*2*2`
- `27 = 3*3*3`

Among those values, 27 is nearer to 3, so it should be displayed as output.

Comment: Please provide more information. Which language are you using? What have you tried so far? Which problmes did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mixing up *digit* with *number*. Digits are just `0-9`.
Having said that, from the description you are giving I believe you want to compute the smallest difference between a given number (e.g. 21) and the cubed values of the closest two integer values to the cubic root of said number.

So for 21 it would be:

- Cubic root = `21 ** (1/3) ~ 2,75`
- Two closest integers:

  - `2`
  - `3`
- Their cubed values

  - `2 ** 3 =  8`
  - `3 ** 3 = 27`
- Difference to given number `21`

  - `|  8  - 21 | = 13`
  - `| 27  - 21 | =  6`
- Smallest difference

  - `6` which is obtained when cubing `3` so print `3`

Here a Python script that will do exactly that.

```py
import sys


# helper function to check whether a string can be parsed as float
def represents_float(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


# ask user to input a number
number_str = input("Please enter a number: ")
if not represents_float(number_str):
    print("You must enter a number")
    sys.exit(1)
number = float(number_str)

# calculate cubic root
cubic_root = number ** (1/3)

# get closest int values
smaller = int(cubic_root)
bigger = smaller + 1

# calculate difference
smaller_diff = abs(smaller ** 3 - number)
bigger_diff = abs(bigger ** 3 - number)

# print the one with smaller difference
if smaller_diff < bigger_diff:
    print(smaller)
else:
    print(bigger)
```

Expected output (if entering 21)

```py
Please enter a number: 21
3
```